# Authorize.net get Payment form are different form When I update it in my login

Tags: forms, payment, authorize.net

I am receiving the following Payment form which doesn't looks professional. Any idea how to use the default payment form from Authorize.NET

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqtko.png) that is i received using

Continue to Authorize.net to Payment Page
    Continue to next page

but my Default form is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viuE1.png)

How I get it my account-> payment form

Continue to Authorize.net to Payment Page
    Continue to next page